# Как buildozer заставить упаковывать Python 3.7.6

Tags: python, kivy

При создание apk файла при помощи buildozer. Файл собирается с python 3.8.1 Хотелось бы получить apk c python 3.7.6 или любым другим. Но настройки buildozer.spec python3==3.7.6 собирает не рабочие apk. Как собрать apk с версией питона, которой я хочу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При работе на телефоне вылетает ошибка

```
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Проблема была что buildozer собирал пакет c python3.8.1. Не какие махинации с id мне не помоги меня выручила строчка в buildozer.spec

```
requirements = hostpython3==3.7.5,python3==3.7.5,kivy,kivymd,sqlite3
```

С python 3.7.6 apk не работает, советую попробовать 3.7.5